# java.nio.MappedByteBuffer virtual/physical address

Tags: java, ios, buffer, nio, mmap

My knowledge of direct mapped buffer in practice is

> direct buffers always live outside of the garbage-collected heap.

So I guess it is meaningful and possible to figure some interesting information out at runtime. Specifically, How could I get the starting virtual address of buffer, starting physical address of buffer, and buffer size? I'm using ubuntu, and is also very curious with the virtual -> physical translation part. Is there any tool to achieve this?

Comment: It's meaningful, but it's not necessarily possible. The API documentation doesn't provide a mechanism for accessing that information.

Comment: It doesn't need to be from API. Is there any other application/ tool from the os side to figure it out?

Comment: Sure. But you didn’t even tell which OS you are using. And you tagged your question wrong. If you want to know how to get the physical address for a logical one, it has nothing to do with Java.

Comment: Thanks for comment. You are right, it's two separate problems and I'm not making it clear enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You know the buffer size because you created it.

You can get the virtual address via JNI.

There is no way to get the physical address, and nothing useful you could do with it if you could.

Comment: Since I'm working on the hardware side for the buffer, the physical address is actually very important for me. It should be conceptually possible to figure it out using tool from OS side. I'm just curious what is the tool.

Comment: If you're inside the kernel you can get the physical address of course, but then you don't have Java or the MappedByteBuffer. You'll have to explain your problem in more detail.

Comment: That's my problem. Is there a specific way to get this? Say is it possible for me to launch a system call from my java program to "peek into kernel" for the physical address?